# efficiently find indexes of nlargest elements in a python list

Tags: python

We can use heapq nlargest to obtain the values of the nlargest elements.
I need to find the *indexes* of the nlargest elements.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Build a tuple of index and value, sort by value and get the index from the tuple.

Comment: Index the returned list? It's not clear what your blocker is because you've shared no code

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
import heapq

values = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(values)
n = 3

pairs = heapq.nlargest(n, zip(values, range(len(values))))
indices = [i for value, i in pairs]

print(values)   # [0, 2, 8, 1, 5, 7, 4, 6, 3, 9]
print(pairs)    # [(9, 9), (8, 2), (7, 5)]
print(indices)  # [9, 2, 5]
```

This seems to be only very slightly faster than an alternative using `enumerate`. Here is some timing code:

```
setup = """
import random
import heapq
import timeit
import operator

values = list(range(10000))
random.shuffle(values)
n = 200

key = operator.itemgetter(1)
"""

stmt1 = """
pairs = heapq.nlargest(n, zip(values, range(len(values))))
indices = [i for value, i in pairs]
"""

stmt2 = """
pairs = heapq.nlargest(n, enumerate(values), key=key)
indices = [i for i, value in pairs]
"""

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(stmt1, setup, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt2, setup, number=1000))
```

Comment: An aside: isn't this back-to-front? Shouldn't the index be the first value e.g. from `enumerate`? I naturally read as though the first value is the index.

Comment: @roganjosh we want to sort by the values, not the indices, hence I'm not using enumerate.

Comment: I mention `enumarate` only in the context that usually we handle `index, value`, not `value, index`